# roslaunch rostopic pub file find package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, rostopic, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I publish a message from a file, found with rospack find, using rostopic pub -f from a launch file?

```
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="arbitrary_node_name" args="pub topic_name msg_type -l -f $(find package_name)/message_details.yaml" output="screen" />
```

doesn't publish anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360575/roslaunch-rostopic-pub-file-find-package/) by [noob_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/58294/noob_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-08-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noob_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/58294/noob_ros/) on 2020-08-31**:
Correction: message is published but only partially (message_details specifies several ros messages separated by '---' but only first message is published)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> message is published but only partially (message_details specifies several ros messages separated by '---' but only first message is published)

it seems things are actually working as they should.

According to the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_pub) (emphasis mine):

> `-f FILE`

> Read message fields from YAML file. YAML syntax is equivalent to output of `rostopic echo`. Messages are separated using YAML document separator `---`. **To use only the first message in a file, use the `--latch` option.**

(this is the same info you'd get when running `rostopic pub --help` btw)

Note how it mentions the *latch option* and how that causes `rostopic pub` to only publish "*the first message*".

You have the `-l` command line option in your `args` attribute in the `.launch` file you show:

```
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="arbitrary_node_name" args="pub topic_name msg_type -l -f $(find package_name)/message_details.yaml" output="screen" />
```

That would be the short version of `--latch`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1